# the link to the latest DOM specification

Tags: javascript, dom

I read the latest DOM specification, which is under draft, that the new DOM model provides APIs for checking dynamically added event handlers. I couldn't find the link to that site and didn't find it using google. Does anyone has the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Document Object Model (DOM) Technical Reports](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) page. That page contains links to all the specifications for DOM levels 1, 2, and 3, plus associated information.

In particular, it sounds like you would be most interested in the [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 3 Events Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/).

Comment: I've got it here for the future reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-EventListenerList